# How to test Java App without APIs in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, jmx

Is it possible to test simple Java app with few classes without any endpoint in JMeter?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting? Please provide more information.

Comment: No, I don't think that it could be possibile

Comment: @user16358266 So I created a Java app with multi threads for inserting and removing the Objects from list. The purpose of that app is to test the performance of JDK. All tutorials about JMeter are representing the HTTP requests, but is there a way to test performances of an app without any endpoiint?

Comment: And you thinkt that JMETER is somehow a tool to do that ??\ *The software is used to perform performance testing, functional testing, and load testing of **web applications**.*

Comment: Sure it is. Why not? Just run your code and watch what happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is not possible with JMeter, if you want to run performance test on the jvm then [Java Microbenchmark Harness (JMH)](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) is the better choice.